# When I using MTR, why farther node values lower?

Tags: linux, networking

The mtr report like this:

```
shell> mtr --report ec2-122-248-229-83.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
HOST: macserver.local             Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 192.168.12.1               0.0%    10    1.2   2.9   0.9   7.4   2.3
  2.|-- 101.36.89.49               0.0%    10    6.8   5.7   2.1  16.6   4.3
  3.|-- 192.168.17.37              0.0%    10   53.8 164.9   4.9 904.4 304.0
  4.|-- 220.181.105.25             0.0%    10    5.1  11.1   5.1  26.9   7.1
  5.|-- 220.181.0.5                0.0%    10   68.5  15.1   4.9  68.5  19.4
  6.|-- 220.181.0.41               0.0%    10   12.6  10.2   5.0  27.1   6.5
  7.|-- 202.97.53.82               0.0%    10    7.2   9.9   4.9  28.1   6.7
  8.|-- 202.97.58.94               0.0%    10   16.5  10.0   5.2  16.5   3.9
  9.|-- 202.97.61.98               0.0%    10   49.2  46.4  39.0  76.7  11.2
 10.|-- 202.97.121.98              0.0%    10   41.1  43.5  41.1  46.3   1.6
 11.|-- 63-218-213-206.static.pcc  0.0%    10   87.2  77.6  70.3  92.2   7.4
 12.|-- 203.83.223.62              0.0%    10   71.9  74.8  69.9  87.2   5.1
 13.|-- 203.83.223.77              0.0%    10   73.6  73.8  70.2  80.9   3.0
 14.|-- ec2-175-41-128-238.ap-sou  0.0%    10   70.4  73.9  70.4  84.1   4.0
 15.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 16.|-- ec2-122-248-229-83.ap-sou 10.0%    10   82.3  76.0  70.6  88.7   6.1
```

Why is the average of the 16 lines lower than line 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers are designed to route packets as quickly as possible. They're not designed to generate and transmit ICMP errors as quickly as possible. Apparently, the machine at line 11 is very slow at generating ICMP errors.

When you see a lower time past a hop than at that hop, you know that most likely it took that router a significant amount of time to generate an ICMP error and get it going back to you.

And, of course, you have to ignore line 15. You didn't get any replies from that router.